# Find corresponding records over multiple columns for each key value given a sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I'm looking for a (T-)SQL solution to the following question. I have a table with columns

- Key (int, not null),
- Column1 (varchar(30), null), Column2, Column3 (up to Column9 but for brevity I'll stop at 3),
- SortOrder (int, not null)

Values in the `Key` column may be present in multiple rows. As a result set I need a row for each `Key` with values in the `Column1`-`Column3` taken from potentially different rows in the initial data, where `ColumnX` value is not null and ordered by `SortOrder`. Hopefully it's easier to understand this from the example:

| Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | SortOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | C1 | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| Key1 | C10 | C11 | NULL | 2 |
| Key1 | C20 | C21 | C22 | 3 |
| Key2 | NULL | C30 | NULL | 1 |
| Key2 | C40 | C41 | NULL | 2 |

The result set in this case would be

| Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | C1 | C11 | C22 |
| Key2 | C40 | C30 | NULL |

There are 100K-200K rows in the table so I'm looking for a good performing solution. Ideally one which reads the table only once but I'm not sure it's even possible (I'll gladly take analytical functions if they help performance or readability in this case). Suggestions for indexing are also welcome though I assume it will be by (Key, SortOrder) anyway.

I have a query which returns the desired result but I'm not quite happy with readability and especially performance:

```
WITH Keys AS (SELECT Key FROM MyTable GROUP BY Key)
SELECT
Key,
(SELECT TOP(1) A.Column1 FROM MyTable A WHERE A.Column1 IS NOT NULL AND A.Key=Keys.Key ORDER BY SortOrder) AS Column1,
(SELECT TOP(1) A.Column2 FROM MyTable A WHERE A.Column2 IS NOT NULL AND A.Key=Keys.Key ORDER BY SortOrder) AS Column2,
(SELECT TOP(1) A.Column3 FROM MyTable A WHERE A.Column3 IS NOT NULL AND A.Key=Keys.Key ORDER BY SortOrder) AS Column3
FROM Keys
```

Comment: Based on the sample data you'd just use `min()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new IGNORE NULLS option when doing FIRST_VALUE to get that you're looking for.

More old-school alternative is to use `first_value(column1) OVER (partition BY [key] ORDER BY case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end, sortorder)` which manually puts the NULLs last.

Finally, a trick i like is to use aggregate together with padding to generate a combined sort + value column, after which the sort part is removed to leave the Value. This method has the upside that it doesn't require any window functions and is just a simple aggregate.

```sql
SELECT  [key]
,   max(c1) AS c1
,   max(c2) AS c2
,   max(c3) AS c3
,   MAX(c1_old) AS c1_old
,   MAX(c2_old) AS c2_old
,   MAX(c3_old) AS c3_old
,   STUFF(MIN(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + CAST(SortOrder AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + column1), 1, 10, '') AS c1_agg
,   STUFF(MIN(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + CAST(SortOrder AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + column2), 1, 10, '') AS c2_agg
,   STUFF(MIN(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + CAST(SortOrder AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + column3), 1, 10, '') AS c3_agg
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   first_value(column1) ignore nulls OVER(partition BY [key] ORDER BY sortorder rows between unbounded preceding and current row) c1
    ,   first_value(column2) ignore nulls OVER(partition BY [key] ORDER BY sortorder rows between unbounded preceding and current row) c2
    ,   first_value(column3) ignore nulls OVER(partition BY [key] ORDER BY sortorder rows between unbounded preceding and current row) c3
    
    ,   FIRST_VALUE(column1) OVER(partition BY [key] ORDER BY case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end, sortorder rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS c1_old
    ,   FIRST_VALUE(column2) OVER(partition BY [key] ORDER BY case when column2 is null then 1 else 0 end, sortorder rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS c2_old
    ,   FIRST_VALUE(column3) OVER(partition BY [key] ORDER BY case when column3 is null then 1 else 0 end, sortorder rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS c3_old
    
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (N'Key1', N'C1', NULL, NULL, 1)
        ,   (N'Key1', N'C10', N'C11', NULL, 2)
        ,   (N'Key1', N'C20', N'C21', N'C22', 3)
        ,   (N'Key2', NULL, N'C30', NULL, 1)
        ,   (N'Key2', N'C40', N'C41', NULL, 2)
    ) t ([Key],Column1,Column2,Column3,SortOrder)
    ) x
GROUP BY [key]
```

Output:

| key | c1 | c2 | c3 | c1_old | c2_old | c3_old | c1_agg | c2_agg | c3_agg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | C1 | C11 | C22 | C1 | C11 | C22 | C1 | C11 | C22 |
| Key2 | C40 | C30 | NULL | C40 | C30 | NULL | C40 | C30 | NULL |

Comment: Just 1 table scan (+ segmenting+window spool+stream aggregates)! Splendid result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As @siggemannen explained, SQL Server 2022 introduced the `IGNORE NULLS` argument to the analytic functions, so this is probably the first possible option. A similar approach uses `DISTINCT` and `FIRST_VALUE()` with `IGNORE NULLS` (to ignore NULL values) and `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` (to use the entire window frame):

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('Key1', 'C1',  NULL,  NULL,  1),
   ('Key1', 'C10', 'C11', NULL,  2),
   ('Key1', 'C20', 'C21', 'C22', 3),
   ('Key2', NULL,  'C30', NULL,  1),
   ('Key2', 'C40', 'C41', NULL,  2)
) v ([Key], Column1, Column2, Column3, SortOrder)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   [Key],
   Column1 = FIRST_VALUE(Column1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY SortOrder ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
   Column2 = FIRST_VALUE(Column2) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY SortOrder ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
   Column3 = FIRST_VALUE(Column3) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY SortOrder ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM Data
```

Result:

| Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | C1 | C11 | C22 |
| Key2 | C40 | C30 | *null* |

Comment: Why would I use UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING if I'm only interested in the FIRST_VALUE?

Comment: @AndrejKuklin, to get the same values for all rows for each `[key]` and then use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: This works, but at least on my data I get an execution plan with 2 additional table spools and nested loops to them (the version from siggemannen just reads the table ones, makes segmenting+window spool and stream aggregates). The execution time/logical reads/memory grant are also better, so I will mark his solution as answer. Thanks for your help!